# how can I find total excluding certain row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Apology if this question has been answered before. In the Summary column I would like to calculate total values for each UserID, excluding Fee which is always 19. As you see there are duplicate UserID's.

I was thinking of using SUMIF'S something like...

=SUMIF(Value, Name,<>"Fee,<>

then I couldn't get it right.

So for example UserID 4836344 total value would be 97.83.

What formula should be used to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me.

P.S - Let me know if you cannot see the image below.

[image]

Comment: `=SUMIF(Name,"<>Fee",VALUE)`

Comment: @ScottCraner - that will calculate total values for all userID's. I would like to show total values for each UserID'

Comment: `=sumifs(<value column>, <name column>, "<>fee", <userid column>, 4836344)` (see [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B)). Also, explain how user 4836344's non-fee total is 97.83.

Comment: @Jeeped - that was my typo error. For 4836344 total value should be 117.46. The formula you recommend is giving 117.15 which I don't understand because I agree with your formula. Have I missed something... =SUMIFS(Value, Name, "<>Fee", UserID, "4836344")

Comment: @Jeeped - Can there be way of avoiding entering UserID value everytime in the formula because there is over 5 thousand records.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot check your results beyond a cursory glance as I simply refuse to retype data from images. See [Why not images of Code and Sample Data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812).

Comment: @Jeeped - The output result works well elsewhere.  I was trying to be helpful in regards to screenshot. Thanks for the formula

Comment: total value should be 117.15. It's been a long day.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add another column EffectiveValue that would contain effective value that needs to be added to the total sum. Formula for that column would be something like '=If([Name]="Fee";0;[Value])'.

Then I would sort table by UserId column.

After that I would use Data -> Subtotals feature to produce total sum per user. In wizard you would specify that on every change in UserId calculate sum of EffectiveValue

Sorry if there are syntax mistakes & formatting, but I am writing  from mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

You got your `SUMIFS` formula almost right. You just need to include the `<>` within the quotation marks like so:

```
=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$19,$A$2:$A$19,A2,$D$2:$D$19,"<>Fee")
```

<sub>The above assumes that your sample table starts at `A1` with UserID and continues through column `E` with the values. The above formula would go into cell `F2` as the first summary and should be copied down. Keep in mind to adjust the range to include more rows (here only through row 19).</sub>

If you have the above sample as a table then you can also use the following formula for `F2` and Excel will automatically copy it down:

```
=SUMIFS([value],[userid],A2,[name],"<>Fee")
```

To convert your table to an "Excel recognized table" select the entire table and press `Ctrl` + `T` [as described in more detail on Microsoft's website](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Create-an-Excel-table-in-a-worksheet-E81AA349-B006-4F8A-9806-5AF9DF0AC664).

For more information on "Tables in Excel" you might want to read the following articles:

1. [Overview of Excel tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)
2. [Use Excel tables to manage information](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Use-Excel-tables-to-manage-information-1c3d9852-4b0b-4496-a1fc-30c5121fb05e)

Comment: what is Strg that you need to press?

Comment: Got a european keyboard. On yours that would be `Ctrl`. Fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Used a german keyboard while visiting a friend once.  Was funny when system setting got changed cause then a lot of the label keys would type different letters from what you might expect.  But that was also more than a decade ago.  I did learn something new today though.  thanks for the heads up on Strg!